# Running CoreLocation in Swift Playground Instance

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I was trying to prototype a basic class for handling getting Geo Coord for my app and wanted to run it in a Swift Playground instance, but the delegate doesnt seem to get called.

Below is the code. Any advice RE: debugging would be helpful.

Is it even possible to run in the IDE.

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import CoreLocation


var str = "Hello, playground"


class GeoCordDelegate: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("Updated Location")
        println(locationMgr.location.coordinate.latitude)
        println(locationMgr.location.coordinate.longitude)
    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("Error while updating location " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

}


let locationMgr = CLLocationManager()

locationMgr.delegate = GeoCordDelegate()
locationMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Answer (score 2):

For Xcode 9

```
import CoreLocation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true 

// Address to Geocode
let address = "Champ de Mars, 5 Avenue Anatole France, 75007 Paris, France"

print("Starting Geocoding")
CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
  let coordinate = placemarks!.first!.location!.coordinate
  print("Completed Geocoding, Latitude: \(coordinate.latitude), Longitude: \(coordinate.longitude)")
  PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution() 
}

print("End of Playground")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since CoreLocation runs asynchronously, you need to enable asynchronous operation in your playground.

Try:

```
import XCPlayground
XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(continueIndefinitely: true)
```

Comment: tried that, but still doesn't execute any of the print statements

Comment: Yeah, you have some other problems in your code, change locationMgr to manager (or vice-versa) and you'll have problems actually getting  it to work at all because you can't set the simulated location for an iOS playground and may not be able to get anything useful out of the OS X simulator.

Comment: Also since delegating objects don't retain their delegates by convention, you're GeoCordDelegate object is immediately released, split it out into a separate let statement.  It still won't work, but it'll be closer :)

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone still wants to do this, here's an example that worked for me in Xcode 7.1 with up-to-date APIs:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa
import XCPlayground
import CoreLocation

var currentPage = XCPlayground.XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage
currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true // Sets up the constant running of the playground so that the location can update properly


let locationMgr = CLLocationManager()

class GeoCordDelegate: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {
        print("Updated Location: " + newLocation.description)
    }
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Error while updating location " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

let geoCoordDelegate = GeoCordDelegate()
locationMgr.delegate = geoCoordDelegate
locationMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
```

The first time it runs you will be prompted to allow access to location for the Example-n-.app.